GraphQl "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription" ERROR
fastapi code
@strawberry.type
class com:
    userId: Optional[int]
@strawberry.type
class Subscription:
    @strawberry.subscription
    async def commentAdded(self, userId: str) -> AsyncGenerator[com, None]:
        yield  com(userId=11)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

I am using it from next js frontend using apollo client
    const { data: dataNotif, loading: loadingNOtif, error:errorNotif } = useSubscription(
        COMMENTS_SUBSCRIPTION,
        { variables: {
                userId: "test"
            },
        }
    );

and this is the query that I use
export const COMMENTS_SUBSCRIPTION = gql(`
  subscription commentAdded($userId: String!) {
    commentAdded(userId: $userId) {
      userId
    }
  }
`);

When I test that from http://localhost:8000/graphql interface using this query
subscription MySubscription {
  commentAdded(userId: "test") {
    userId
  }
}

it works fine and returns this
{
  "data": {
    "commentAdded": {
      "userId": 11
    }
  }
}

but when I try to use it from my frontend I get this error
ERROR:strawberry.execution:Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription.commentAdded.

GraphQL request:2:3
1 | subscription commentAdded($userId: String!) {
2 |   commentAdded(userId: $userId) {
  |   ^
3 |     userId
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/databiz32/Videos/WEB/other/grats-backend/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/graphql/execution/execute.py", line 540, in execute_field
    completed = self.complete_value(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/databiz32/Videos/WEB/other/grats-backend/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/graphql/execution/execute.py", line 620, in complete_value
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription.commentAdded.

